# How to change data value in using method in vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

So I have a component Carousel card and I added the indicator navigation outside the carousel. The indicator navigation is change its active dots really well with class binding whenever I swipe the Carousel card.

```
<div class="indicator-nav">
  <div v-for="i in items" class="dots" :class="{ 'dots-active': i - 1 === dotsActive }" @click="active(i)"/>
</div>
```

The Carousel card has activeCard that set to 0 on data, that means the active Carousel card by default is the first index of the cards.

```
data () {
    return {
        activeCard: 0
    }
},
methods: {
    active(i) {
        this.activeCard = i - 1
        console.log(this.activeCard) //the value change based on the indicator value, but when I check on Vue devtools, the value didn't change so the Card also not changing
    }
}
```

Whenever I swipe the Carousel card, the value in activeCard props will change. But the problem is, when I click the indicator navigation dots, it doesn't change the activeCard value. It remains 0.

What I expect is whenever I click the dots, then the activeCard value will also change based on the dots index that I clicked so the Card is obviously will change also. Did I miss something?

Comment: Do you have a `@click` on the dots so that you can set the index to the desired value.

Comment: Yup, I already have it on the dots @kissu

Comment: Please provide us a proper [repro], having 5 lines of code will not help us and is ineffective for everybody.

Comment: typo, you're using `dotsActive` but the model is `activeCard`

Comment: also missing key on loop